# Application crashes with JVM 1.6_33 and not with 1.7_25

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, crash, jvm

Our application crashes on JVM 1.6_33 only on windows after we have changed from Vector to ArrayList.
We are working in a multi-threaded environment.I suspect the crash ocurres because of an unsynchronized access to the ArrayList.
The Java errorlog points to a method where this ArrayList is read and changed:
com.swt.lib.ConnectionPool.getConnection(I)Lcom/swt/lib/Connection;+10

If I synchronize the respective method the application also does not crash.
And the application is working on:
- JVM 1.6_33 or  1.7_25 on Linux
- JVM 1.7_25 on windows

There were some reasons why it was changed from Vector to ArrayList, but I can´t remember. So I don´t want to change it back.

As I don't exactly know where in the code the problem happens, I can't post the exact code. I have a ConnectionPool and I suspect the problem is somewhere here:

```
public Connection getConnection(ArrayList<Connection> connectionPool){
        Connection connection = connectionPool.get(0);
        connectionPool.remove(0);
return connection;
    }   
    public void free(Connection connection, ArrayList<Connection> connectionPool){
        connectionPool.add(connection);
    }
```

Before we used the ArrayList we used Vector. If it is an error of synchronization there should be an exception and no JVM crash?

The application crashes approximately every 24 hours.

Now the application is running on a JVM 1.7_25. But I don´t trust that it will stay like this.

Does anyone know why it works with JVM 1.7_25 and not with 1.6_33?

I forgot to post the name of the error: Exception_Access_Violation

I just saw an advice on www.java.com: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml

I wonder, if the crash of the JVM has to do with the mentioned or if it is a synchronization error...

Thanks for any advice,
Roote

Comment: Can you post the relevant code ? Thanks !

Comment: Please show the stack trace of the exception (or at least the first few lines of it).

Comment: It is an  Exception_Access_Violation. Can a synchronization error cause a crash of the JVM? Thanks for any advice....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your code may have some concurrent accesses going on; the problem is likely to be intermittent. Have you considered using [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)?

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);
```

Otherwise, I'd just synchronize access to the list instance with a `synchronized(list)` block (which you reported works).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Elliott. I think what you are proposing is what we have to do. I don't want to synchronize the whole block as I am afraid of a dead-lock.
But do you know, why there is a difference between windows and Linux and JVM 1.6 and 1.7?

Comment: Because Windows and Linux are different. JVM 1.6 and 1.7 are different. And, I suspect your problem is actually intermittent. If you have a short section of code that can consistently cause this please post, and I'll see if I can explain it.

Comment: Only if you use the fail fast form of ArrayList. That doesn't seem like "a" (safe) Connection pool. Maybe use [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)?

Comment: Yes, I think we should implement the fail-fast form of the ArrayList. And later may be the DBCP. But if there is an synchronization error, shouldn't I get a normal exception and not an Exception_Access_Violation from the JVM?

Comment: If you use the fail-fast form of the ArrayList, I think you will be seeing a lot of normal exception(s).

Comment: I will investigate this a bit more. Thanks a lot!